# Multiple row in one row table

Tags: php, html, tabular

Does anyone know how can I have two rows on one column but only a single cell

```
---------------------
      | x    |      |
    Z |------| A    |  
      | y    |      |
------------- -------
```

My table in PHP looks like this

Trans Table
Transaction ID - 1
Transactiion date - Feb 7

Transdetails Table

Details ID - 1
Transaction ID - 1
Medicine - 1

Details ID - 2
Transaction ID - 1
Medicine - 2

I need to show both medicine on one Transaction ID in one row

Comment: you mean in html ..?. php is server side  ..

Comment: ' table in PHP' !?

Comment: If you are asking to merge database tables like you do in Excel, not going to happen. If you are trying to display data in html in the same way you would merge an Excel spreadsheet, yes it can be done.

Comment: Can you explain your diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

With `<td rowspan="n">` you can achive that layout with a HTML Table.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2">z</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td rowspan="2">a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```